# how would I do rotated mansonry layout, where height is constant and width variable

Tags: css

Everyone on the internet talks about mansorny where height is free and width is same.

[image]

I need to create mansonry where height is constant and width is not restricted.

I am aiming for this kind of layout that can be found on Microsoft Photos webapp.

Whats my best option to achive this kind of layout, can I do this with css purely, perhaps css grid? Has anyone created anything like this and has some examples or tutorials to look at?

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I know people help with code here, but I have not tried anything yet since I am starting on this task and its not a simple task to align all images perfectly end to end and let them have constant height and free width. I am looking for someone who has done this kind of layout to give me some tips how I may go about, should I use pure css or do I need js solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container div{
    height: 100px /*the Height you want*/;
    position: relative;
    float: left /*You can use display:inline-block*/;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container div img{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

</style>


<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```